# how to convert mongodb date to JSON representation of a 64-bit signed integer giving the number of milliseconds since epoch UTC

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

My question tells what I want to ask.

I'm thinking client will send me the calendar date in this format,I'll save this in my mongodb and I'll also return the date in the same format to the client whenever required.

Is it a best and efficient way ?

Thanks for any kind of help.

**Edit:**
If there is something wrong in my question please tell me why? what is best way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There is a `.getTime()` function for a date:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTime());
// 1454672518592
```